# Oracle Custom sql in Liferay

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jakarta-ee, liferay

I am using oracle DB and writing the custom SQL in life-ray.
    If I am missing any one column name in **SQL query** then its throwing below error, Please help to avoid this error because I want to escape some columns names.

```
General Example (not from code)...,
    1) select a,b,c from alphabets; (its working fine).
    2) select b,c from alphabets;(its throwing below error).
```

Comment: Share your complete code!

Comment: @user3380194 added the code you've posted to the original question

Comment: Please add information according to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site to all of your crossposts

Comment: ...and the code that you posted doesn't even compile. You have different problems than a missing column name... (please edit your question next time instead of adding a comment with code)

Comment: @user3380194 and on which of the many sites that you've crossposted this to would you like the answer? I'm still missing the reaction to my first comment regarding http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site (on *all* sites that you crossposted to). Until *you* let everyone know where else you are asking for the same question, there's *no reason* for any (free) volunteer to help you: The problem might long be solved on another platform. It'd be quite respectful to free volunteers to do this from the beginning. Read that link on meta!

Comment: @Olaf, I have removed from other blogs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I rarely do raw hibernate these days, but I expect         `queryObject.addEntity("COMROLETAB", COMROLETABImpl.class);` to require data for *all* fields of COMROLETABImpl, which you don't provide in sql2.

There's another option if `sql1` is actually coming in from out of the scope that you post here, because you're defining `sqls` while you're referring to `sql1`.

Note that the code snippet that you're posting here is also leaking session objects - sooner or later you'll run out of database connections. You'll need to read on error handling and resource handling.